# Erro Unsupported operand types

Tags: php

Quando importo o xml de imovel ele faz a conta de acordo com os critérios. Um dos critério é o preço, os mais caros aparecem primeiro, para isso eu dividi o valor do preço por 10 milhões e soma o resultado no ranking dele.

Ex: Imóvel com nota 1500 + (preço de 10.000.000/10.000.000) = 1501

Mas quando faço essa conta, ele trava a importação e dá esse erro:

> Erro Unsupported operand types on line 332

Que é a linha onde acaba o if do código abaixo:

```
if ($tipo==Venda){
$ordem = $ordem + $preco/10000000;
}
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Primeiro: há as devidas aspas envolvendo o termo "Venda" na condição? Segundo: quais são os tipos das variáveis?

Answer (score 2):

Para "depurar" as variáveis, antes da `if` faça:

```
var_dump($ordem, $preco);
if ($tipo==Venda){
```

E então irá notar o problema,  `$ordem` ou `$preco` **não são números**, um deles deve ser um `array` ou `null` e então não será possível fazer a operação matemática, o que causa o erro.

Isto deve estar ocorrendo porque esta usando em um `while` ou `for` sem checar os valores que estão sendo usados adicionados ao `$ordem` e `$preco`, você pode também estar usando a variável em diferentes lugares, tipo tentando reaproveitar uma variável para fazer duas coisas, algo que realmente pode causar muitos problemas.

Outro problema, que talvez não tenha ligação direta, é o `if` que "parece" estar errado:

```
if ($tipo==Venda){
```

O `Venda` teria que ser assim `'Venda'`, a não ser que venda seja uma *constante* (mas isto é outro problema).

Comment: deu isso aqui:
int(1100) string(10) "1638000.00" int(1100) string(10) "6500000.00" int(1600) string(10) "4500000.00" int(100) array(0) { }

Comment: Veja @LeandroTeraoka um deles mostrou `array(0) { }`, ou seja uma das chamadas esta recebendo array, tem que corrigir dentro do seu `while` (creio que seja os resultados do banco)

Comment: desculpa, não entendei, não manjo mt. tem como eu saber quem está vindo como array?

Comment: De onde vem o valor de `$ordem`? É do banco de dados (de um while)? Posta o código todo no pastebin.com pra eu ver

Comment: Perdão, falei banco, mas na verdade o problema deve ser em um for do conteudo do xml, algum deles deve estar ser o preço e o parse do XML deve estar pegando como se fosse uma "tag" vazia o que é convertido para um array vazio. Estou só supondo, sem o código não tem como ajudar mais que isto, se puder dar detalhes ajudaria.

Comment: o código é gigante...rs, 
o $preco que está dando erro. eu defini ele para $preco=4500000 antes do if, aí não deu erro e funcionou certinho.
o $preco é definido assim $preco = $property['price'];. ele pega o valor do xml que está em <price>4500000.00</price>
se eu jogo o $preco no campo preço do banco de dados, ele aparece o valor normal (ex: 450000.00)
Eu testei importando um xml com apenas alguns imóveis e funcionou normalmente

Comment: @LeandroTeraoka tente criar um exemplo minimo que reproduza o erro e me manda.